# Noise cancellation device for entire rooms

Tags: acoustics, noise

I recently met a group who were exploring active noise cancellation devices for entire rooms. Their approach essentially revolved around detecting incident noise on the room and blasting inverse soundwaves in the direction of a person in the room.

Can someone please explain if this approach holds any merit? Why would this be a better approach over other tried and tested approaches for noise reduction viz. double glazed windows or padding surfaces with sound absorbing material?

Comment: Try reading about [superposition of waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle) and [active noise cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_noise_control). Active noise cancellation is a common technique employed by (relatively) high-end noise cancelling headphones, so technically it qualifies as 'tried and tested', just like conventional passive techniques like sound-absorbing materials.

Comment: Active noise cancelling headphones cancel the noise in a very small volume of space, using a speaker and a microphone that located in that small volume. And, the "active" part only works for frequencies below a few hundred Hz. Basically, the technique only works within a volume of space that is significantly smaller than the wavelength of the sound that you want to cancel. The instantaneous sound pressure at different points in a typical room will be different, even for the bass notes. There's no way that one device can cancel the sound everywhere in the room.

Comment: The comparative merits of particular technologies is an **engineering** issue, which is *off topic* for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds wavelengths are smaller than typical-size rooms. As sound propagates through rooms, bouncing around, getting absorbed and reflected, etc, the pressure field inside the room becomes very complicated.  You can't have enough independent emitters to cancel all that.

What you can do is to cancel the sound pressure profile at a smaller number of places that matter:

- at the listeners - this is what sound cancelling headphones do
- at the sources - this is what [active noise source reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_noise_control) does

For very small rooms, i.e. car interiors, it's possible to multiple actuators to remove a large fraction of noise, but note that because of the sensitivity of our hearing, reducing noise by even 90% doesn't make that much of a difference.  You have to [do a really, really good job](https://www.forbes.com/sites/geoffreymorrison/2014/02/21/are-noise-cancelling-headphones-worth-it/#7e3f7c46d566) at removing acoustic noise power before people will say "It's gone!"

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot! As a follow up question: How feasible is it to cancel the sound pressure profile from afar? For eg. For the sake of argument, say we had the pressure profile inside a room completely figured out. Could a speaker blasting out the inverse soundwave have a cancelling effect at a particular point?